# LUIS Authoring resource vs Prediction resource - 403 Error Out of Volume

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

Following couple of Questions I understand that the LUIS Authoring resource has a limit of 1000/month for testing in luis.ai and generating the Json view format.

[LUIS gives 403 error “Out of call volume quota.” when testing in portal with using Authoring Resource F0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67932166/luis-gives-403-error-out-of-call-volume-quota-when-testing-in-portal-with-usi)

[LUIS gives 403 response with "Out of call volume quota."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417385/luis-gives-403-response-with-out-of-call-volume-quota)

All the instances we have can be created within the Authoring resource only, while within the app / instance we can have a prediction resource. Currently, I have added prediction resource within my app, but I am not able to get through this error. Is there any other settings change that I should follow to make this happen? (include or use the prediction key etc.)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [Luis Bot -> Error: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/3299)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve Luis - 403 Out of call volume quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319739/how-to-resolve-luis-403-out-of-call-volume-quota)